# How to UNinstall php7.2-fpm WITHOUT installing Apache 2 (on a LEMP machine)

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, php-7.2, fpm

This may sound stupid, but my weird configuration seems to *force* an Apache2 *installation* when attempting to **un**install `php7.2-fpm`! (I use `nginx` and the last thing I want to see on my server is an Apache installation...)

Here is the scenario: I'm stuck with a Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS installation (sorry, I have no control over it, I can only maintain it, use `apt` to install whatever I want, but *not* upgrade Ubuntu to a contemporary version.

Over the years, as expected, Ubuntu 16.04 became to be dropped by many package maintainers, especially those from the official Ubuntu repositories; thus, I had no choice but to add *lots* of alternative repositories.

Also, over time, I've been upgrading PHP. The first thing was to drop 5.6, years ago. Then came the time to retire 7.0, and eventually 7.1 as well. In the mean time, I had installed versions 7.2, 7.3 and 7.4, as each and every site hosted on that server (there are not that many, btw) was scrupulously tested to make sure it continued to work on recent versions of PHP.

Right now, *all* sites I've got run on PHP 7.4, except for two, which still require PHP 7.3, until the underlying application software is made compatible with 7.4 (which will happen in a few weeks or months, I'm sure). I can safely remove PHP 7.2, since it's not used any more.

Alas, it seems that it was not entirely removed — even though it does *not* get launched at boot, neither is it called from anything. If I try to remove it, however, I get the following:

```bash
# apt remove php7.2-fpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php7.2 libapr1
  libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following packages will be REMOVED
  php7.2-fpm
The following NEW packages will be installed
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapache2-mod-php7.2 libapr1
  libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0
0 to upgrade, 10 to newly install, 1 to remove and 16 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,879 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,192 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Obviously, the *last* thing I want is to have Apache 2 installed again. Also, iI believe it's the first time that I see `apt` wishing to *install* something when I request it to *delete* a package!

Here is what I get from `apt show`:

```bash
# apt show php7.2-fpm
Package: php7.2-fpm
Version: 7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Priority: optional
Section: php
Source: php7.2
Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers <team+pkg-php@tracker.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 4,960 kB
Provides: php-fpm, phpapi-20170718
Depends: libmagic1, libpcre3 (>= 2:8.41), mime-support, php7.2-cli, php7.2-common (= 7.2.31-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php7.2-json, php7.2-opcache, procps, systemd | systemd-tmpfiles, tzdata, ucf, init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~), libapparmor1 (>= 2.7.0~beta1+bzr1772), libargon2-0 (>= 0~20160406~), libc6 (>= 2.15), libsodium23 (>= 1.0.14), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0), libsystemd0, libxml2 (>= 2.8.0), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Suggests: php-pear
Download-Size: 1,394 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Description: server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
 This package provides the Fast Process Manager interpreter that runs
 as a daemon and receives Fast/CGI requests.  Note that MOST Apache users
 probably want the libapache2-mod-php7.2 package.
 .
 The following extensions are built in: Core date filter hash libxml openssl
 pcre Reflection session sodium SPL standard zlib.
 .
 PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a widely-used
 open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited
 for web development and can be embedded into HTML.
```

Note that Apache 2 is *not* installed, although I believe it had been installed once (years ago)  — I never used/configured it, but *maybe* it came pre-installed, I don't know, I'm just speculating here) — even though `apt` says it's not installed any longer, there *might* be some old files around which 'confuse' `apt` when removing a package...

I cannot find this very weird dependency, though, nor how to fix it (so many options I've tried...)

I have *not* tried to allow `apt` to go on and install Apache 2, and immediately issue a `delete/purge` request on package `apache2`. Maybe that will fix the repository dependencies...

As usual, I thank you in advance for bearing with my beginner questions around `apt`!

---

Note: I've obviously Googled for a solution, as well as doing plenty of searches here on SO. While I found a lot of examples about installing/removing all sorts of PHP versions, mostly with Apache, sometimes with `nginx` as well, I haven't come across a solution for my specific case. Is there a command-line option for `apt` to ignore some dependencies when *removing* a package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, by sheer chance, when trying to fix this *again*, I stumbled upon the following explanation: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/trying-to-uninstall-phpmyadmin-dpkg-error-while-cleaning-up

While this is not directly related to my own issue with `php7.2-fpm`, I've noticed a very important thing: the asterisk at the end!

So I basically did:

`apt-get remove php7.2*`

and, for good measure,

`apt-get purge php7.2*`

(surprisingly, there were a few extra packages that had not been removed...)

and, because it cannot hurt...

`apt-get autoremove` (it returned that there was nothing left to remove)

Also, to my astonishment, I *still* found a few old packages from `php7.1` available!! (I deleted them in the same way). And, sadly, because I have such an old base Ubuntu system, I need a few files from `php7.0` just to get a working [Roundcube](https://roundcube.net) (critical for the overall operation of my server), but my next cleanup task will be to figure out how to get rid of it without disturbing `Roundcube`...

Answer (score 1):

If you directly install php 7.2, Apache is installed. Please try this

```
apt-get purge apache2
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
```

Comment: A good idea, but unfortunately `apt-get` says: `Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed`, and then proceeds to do all sorts of stupid things, like attempting to restart `php7.2-fpm`...